# How to persist google api authentication across machines?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am developing a web app using rails backend and ember js front end.
I want to integrate google calendar in my app. Since google doesn't give any ember.js SDK for google API, I am using the Javascript SDK for this purpose.

Now, I want the user to authorize google calendar for my app in one machine. And when he logs out from my app on machine 1 and logs in on machine 2, I want google calendar to be still authorized.

Also, when the oauth token expires automatically after sometime, I want to regenerate it again (by using a refresh token maybe?) rather than asking the user to authorize again. I won't be doing this when the user revokes the permission himself.

Can someone give me some guidance on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't think it's possible to log in one machine and be automatically logged-in in another. You may want to look at using [service accounts for Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth) instead:

> In enterprise applications you may want to programmatically access
>   users data without any manual authorization on their part. In Google
>   Apps domains, the domain administrator can grant to third party
>   applications domain-wide access to its users' data — this is referred
>   as domain-wide delegation of authority. To delegate authority this
>   way, domain administrators can use service accounts with OAuth 2.0.

Implementing refresh tokens are detailed in [Refreshing an access token (offline access)](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline):

```
HTTP/REST implementation:

POST /oauth2/v4/token HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=<your_client_id>&
client_secret=<your_client_secret>&
refresh_token=<refresh_token>&
grant_type=refresh_token
```